# How to show nickname instead of foreign key?

Tags: sqlite, join

`play_by_play` table I want to connect to multiple other tables so I can see the text instead of id. `play_by_play` table has *three* different columns that use `team_id` from another table.

When I run this query I get no results. No error, just no results. I get a few results when removing `AND play_by_play.player3_team_id = team.team_id` so I'm sure there's a correct way.

```
SELECT
    play_by_play.id,
    play_by_play.game_id,
    play_by_play.event_msg_action_type 
FROM play_by_play
    INNER JOIN event_message_type
        ON play_by_play.event_msg_type_id  = event_message_type.id
    INNER JOIN game
        ON game.game_id = play_by_play.game_id
    INNER JOIN team
        ON play_by_play.player1_team_id = team.team_id
        AND play_by_play.player2_team_id = team.team_id
        AND play_by_play.player3_team_id = team.team_id
LIMIT 500
```

[image: Part of the ER Diagram]

Any resources to understand SQL syntax is appreciated. How to put these pieces in the correct order?

Comment: do you mean `INNER JOIN team ON team.team_id IN(play_by_play.player1_team_id, play_by_play.player2_team_id, play_by_play.player3_team_id)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use table team three times
...
INNER JOIN team team1
ON play_by_play.player1_team_id = team1.team_id
INNER JOIN team team2
ON play_by_play.player2_team_id = team2.team_id
INNER JOIN team team3
AND play_by_play.player3_team_id = team3.team_id
...

Comment: I see so I first have to give an alias to the table I'm joining it with. Thank you.

Comment: I'm just gonna comment this here to explain to myself. So I join the two tables like regular. However, if a table multiple foreign key columns that reference the same table then I must make multiple INNER joins for those columns. In addition to that, I must also give each of them an alias since each JOIN connects to a different column. Each alias is like an alias for each connection/JOIN, if I were to not alias the JOINS then SQL wouldn't know which connection/JOIN to reference.